# Event assignment syntax in different Object Pascal dialects

Tags: syntax-error, lazarus, delphi

I'm working on a component that should be shared between Delphi and C++Builder, so I'm using Pascal as the *lingua franca*. Because I don't have Delphi on my computer at home, I first created the component in the Lazarus IDE. Now I "ported" it to Delphi and found an astonishing syntax problem:

This compiles with FPC (but not Delphi):

```
FSync.FSyncMethod := @SyncCheckInput;
```

This compiles with Delphi (but not FPC):

```
FSync.FSyncMethod := SyncCheckInput;
```

How can I share a unit between Lazarus and Delphi despite this syntactic divergence?

Comment: "*a lack of a common (and portable) synchronizing mechanism*" - FreePascal mimics many of Delphi's core classes, include `TThread` and its `Synchronize()` method: [FreePascal Wiki | Multithreaded Application Tutorial | The TThread Class](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Multithreaded_Application_Tutorial#The_TThread_Class)

Comment: @RemyLebeau I needed a non-blocking synchronisation mechanism and I got it with (the thread-safe) `Application.QueueAsyncCall` in Lazarus and `PostMessage` to an invisible Window (via `AllocateHWnd`) in Delphi. Of course, I used the `TThread` class, but `Synchronize` was not helpful in my case because of its rendezvous feature. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: `TThread` also has an asynchronous `Queue()` method.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm afraid there is no `Queue` method in Delphi 4, that I have to use (I'm not sure, I've no D4 or its docs at hand now). So I better remove the sidenote from the question or be more specific about the versions I'm using?

Comment: You did not say which Delphi/FreePascal version you are using. No, `Queue()` does not exist in D4.  FreePascal mimics D7.

Comment: I removed the Note about synchronisation mechanisms. BTW: `TThread.Queue` does currently not exist in the LCL.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Insert this at the beginning of your units:

```
{$IFDEF FPC}{$MODE DELPHI}{$ENDIF}
```

This will instruct FreePascal to use the Delphi dialect to compile the unit. Delphi will ignore the [`{$MODE DELPHI}` directive](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/3.0.0/prog/progsu105.html#x113-1140001.3.22) because `FPC` is not defined.

You can then use this

```
FSync.FSyncMethod := SyncCheckInput;
```

for setting events dynamically.

Comment: That's the kind of solution I was hoping for!